# User confirmation of database update - php + Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an `AJAX` POST which runs a php script which updates `MySQL`. The page is part of a Joomla site. Its part of a series of POSTS which return HTML to div's in the page. It all works well but I currently use a simple echo statement to say "Record Updated !" etc. But I have little control over where this message goes - and I don't know how to remove it when the user moves to another record - I'd like the message to disappear. I've just realised that HTML created by Ajax is "on the fly" - i.e you don't see it when you view source.  So it's not possible to use Javascript and the DOM  to change it. 
What I think I want to do is run a Javascript function within the php - but this doesn't work either !

Any help here appreciated - or an alternative approach to give a database update confirmation message which can then be removed when the user moves to handle another record.

Comment: any code would be helpful. Which javascript library are you using? Mootools? JQuery ?

Comment: If you use firefox, you can select some stuff and do right-click => view selection source. That will give you the current html including anything added by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` statements in php are not shown to the user when you use ajax unless you use the php output in your ajax success function yourself.

So you just need to remove the part of the javascript that adds the ajax return data to the dom / screen (in case of an alert).

As to an alternative solution, you could use a statically fixed status bar that shows up on an update and slides away after a few seconds. I don't know if you are using a javascript library, but using jQuery that would be very easy to implement.